# Cannot resolve symbol 'QDefaultRevisionEntity' when using the org.hibernate.envers package

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have a spring application that uses the org.hibernate.envers package, once I try to compile the application I get this error:

```
java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class QDefaultRevisionEntity
  location: package org.hibernate.envers
```

This is within the generated-source file directory and it extends the Entity that follows:

```
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import org.hibernate.envers.DefaultRevisionEntity;
import org.hibernate.envers.RevisionEntity;
import jakarta.persistence.*;

@Setter @Getter
@Entity
@Table(name = "")
@RevisionEntity(CustomRevisionListener.class)
public class CustomRevisionEntity extends DefaultRevisionEntity {
    private Integer authenticatedUserId;
}
```

Finally this is the generated-file: Where I'm getting the following error(s): **Cannot resolve symbol 'timestamp', Cannot resolve symbol 'id' and Cannot resolve symbol 'QDefaultRevisionEntity'**

```
import static com.querydsl.core.types.PathMetadataFactory.*;

import com.querydsl.core.types.dsl.*;

import com.querydsl.core.types.PathMetadata;
import javax.annotation.processing.Generated;
import com.querydsl.core.types.Path;


/**
 * QCustomRevisionEntity is a Querydsl query type for CustomRevisionEntity
 */
@Generated("com.querydsl.codegen.DefaultEntitySerializer")
public class QCustomRevisionEntity extends EntityPathBase<CustomRevisionEntity> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -697850477L;

    public static final QCustomRevisionEntity customRevisionEntity = new QCustomRevisionEntity("customRevisionEntity");

    public final org.hibernate.envers.QDefaultRevisionEntity _super = new org.hibernate.envers.QDefaultRevisionEntity(this);

    public final NumberPath<Integer> authenticatedUserId = createNumber("authenticatedUserId", Integer.class);

    //inherited
    public final NumberPath<Integer> id = _super.id;

    //inherited
    public final NumberPath<Long> timestamp = _super.timestamp;

    public QCustomRevisionEntity(String variable) {
        super(CustomRevisionEntity.class, forVariable(variable));
    }

    public QCustomRevisionEntity(Path<? extends CustomRevisionEntity> path) {
        super(path.getType(), path.getMetadata());
    }

    public QCustomRevisionEntity(PathMetadata metadata) {
        super(CustomRevisionEntity.class, metadata);
    }

}
```

Here is the `pom.xml` file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>redacted</groupId>
    <artifactId>redacted</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>redacted</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <description>Redacted</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>19</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>mysql</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>-->
<!--            <scope>runtime</scope>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>

<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>-->
<!--&lt;!&ndash;            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>&ndash;&gt;-->
<!--        </dependency>-->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.orm/hibernate-envers -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>-->
<!--            <version>6.3.0.Final</version>-->
<!--            <type>pom</type>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-envers -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>31.1-jre</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity6</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.10.1</version>
            <type>maven-plugin</type>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.awaitility</groupId>
            <artifactId>awaitility</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.darrachequesne</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa-datatables</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>-->
<!--            <version>6.0.4</version>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.11</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>16</source>
                    <target>16</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Have you tried to add default constructor and one without params ?

Comment: @AndreiLisa no but thanks for the suggestion, I'll try it and provide an update.

Comment: @AndreiLisa no the error remains the same

Comment: have you provided `hibernate-envers` to dependency that also have the same version of `hibernate-core` ?

Comment: @AndreiLisa I did not have the `hibernate-core` dependency in my `pom.xml` however when I add the dependency ```<dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>6.3.0.Final</version> 
    </dependency>``` I get the error: `Dependency 'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:' not found`

Comment: `<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>6.3.0.Final</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>`

Comment: just an update, add also in the question body pom.xml file

Comment: @AndreiLisa sorry for the late reply, I'm working with some restrictions. I've added the `pom.xml' code.

Comment: i just have added a answer.

Answer (score 0):

After executed, the maven build with `pom.xml` file that you provide, i can say: I new version of hibernate `org.hibernate:hibernate-envers` has been relocated to `org.hibernate.orm:hibernate-envers` also you have a `WAR` in build output.

[image: war]

The only thing what you should to do is change the dependency imports from:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
    <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

to

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
    <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

You do not need `hibernate-core` dependency it has already imported from `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa`. Be sure that all imports in the project are from `jakarta.` not `javax.` it is very important thing.

I think it will solve the problem.

Comment: I updated the dependency, it's not working so far, so I'm trying to change the `javax` to `jakarta` but it's recommended that I don't modify a generated class, Querydsl generates these classes correct? How do I modify it to use `jakarta` instead of `javax`?

Comment: be sure that when it is going to be generated is using `jakarta` how do you can achieve it, simple upgrade the dependency, from `pom.xml`, to know  from hibernate 6.x is using `jakarta`

Comment: `mvn dependency:tree`  can help you to do it.

Comment: I tried installing maven but no luck.

Comment: Can you share the error message ?

Comment: sure, I'm not getting the same error I was getting yesterday, now I am getting: `Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.jooq:jooq-codegen-maven:3.18.5: Plugin org.jooq:jooq-codegen-maven:3.18.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.jooq:jooq-codegen-maven:3.18.5: Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-maven-plugin/1.8.22/kotlin-maven-plugin-1.8.22.pom`. This error in on a loop in the terminal

Comment: i think it it an topic for another question because dont have anythings relevant with `hibernate-envers` and also if `java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class QDefaultRevisionEntity
  location: package org.hibernate.envers` don`t appear the problem was solved, by the way i wait your feedback about it.

Comment: The `CustomRevisionEntity` extends `DefaultRevisionEntity` and I temporally removed the extension and the file syntax is obviously different but no error..So I think there's something wrong with the `DefaultRevisionEntity` java class, and my hibernate-envers dependency is configured to use the latest version ex: `${hibernate.version}`